# Using Ajax to handle Play Framework requests on external pages

Tags: jquery, post, jquery-mobile, playframework

So all the examples that I have seen, look like they are used within the play framework themselves.

I'm trying to handle a simple login from an external page that would eventually be used on a mobile application using phoneGap.

When I send the ajax request I get a 302 code, which I presume is good since I want to get redrected to an admin page. My problem is that I don't know how to handle the redirecting or maybe that the play Framework is sending the wrong information to me.

This is my ajax call.

```
            $("#loginPage").on('pageinit',function(event){ 
                $("#loginBtn").click(function() { 
                    $surl =  "http://morning-oasis-8528.herokuapp.com/login";
                    $username = $('#username').val();
                    $password = $('#password').val();
                    var bool = new Boolean("TRUE");
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: $surl,
                        data: {username:$username, password:$password, remember:bool},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success :  function(data, textStatus) {
                            if(data.redirect){
                                window.location.href = data.redirect;
                            } else {
                                alert(data);
                            } 
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
```

And this is my html:

```
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
            <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="back">Back</a>         
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">    
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="username">Username :</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required="required" /><br/><br/>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required" />
                <button data-theme="b" id="loginBtn" >Log-In</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" >
            <p>Login Form</p>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Well this now seems a little old, haha.